# based on dropdown list selected value i want to populate data in input text in jsf

Tags: jsf

How to populate data in input text fields coresponding to selected dropdown value.
I have used valuechange listner which is taking the selected value back to my bean and based on that i am fetching data from my database. But I am unable to display it on UI.
And even when code is fetching data from database and took it back to the bean after that page is again reloaded and unable to hold selected value , again fresh page is seen without any selected dropdown value.

Comment: place some code examples m8. Your html form element and the backing bean method that is invoked on the dropdown selection. Then maybe we can go from there.

Comment: @MaciejKowalski: Better to ask for a [mcve] and refere to http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for more details on this and other info to post. 'Some code' is 99% of the time not helpful